# Why doesn't an installed font show up in the font picker dialog?

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2008, fonts

I've installed an OpenType font on my development machine expecting to then be able to choose that font for a label on a form.

The font is available in MS Word so I'm reasonably confident it was installed ok, but I can't see the font in the font-picker dialog for the label in Visual Studio.  I also checked the font settings in Tools > Options and it isn't there either.  Running the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106712/how-to-make-sure-a-font-exists-before-using-it-with-net#106724) doesn't list the font.  I've tried restarting VS.Net.

What else can I do to make this font show up in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GDI+ doesn't support OpenType, only TrueType.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't tried restarting Visual Studio yet, I'd give that a try.

Assuming you did that already, is the font listed in c:\windows\fonts\ okay? If it is, you might want to try removing it and then re-installing that font via the File > Install New Font... menu when you've got that window open.

Just some ideas and things to try. Hope it helps!