# Unable to use Opentype font with visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, opentype

I am using Windows XP, and trying to use MyriadPro Opentype font with Visual Studio 2008.
I can use this font with Wordpad, but Visual Studio IDE does not show this Font in Font property for a control.

Answer (score 2):

By default, .Net does not supports OpenType fonts, because it uses GDI+ to render them, which supports only a very limited subset of OpenType fonts (basically, only the Microsoft ones).

I'm currently looking for a solution. WPF seems to support them, but I don't see any solution for "classic" .Net.

See this question : [Why doesn't an installed font show up in the font picker dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269162/why-doesnt-an-installed-font-show-up-in-the-font-picker-dialog)